# PHP Ruflin/Elastica - how to refresh index on huge data insert

Tags: php, elasticsearch, indexing, elastica

I need to insert about 1.5 million documents to Elasticsearch databse. I do it via PHP library Elastica according [this example (BULK example)](http://elastica.io/getting-started/storing-and-indexing-documents.html#section-add)

I would like to know if it is posible to use call `$elasticaType->getIndex()->refresh();` command at the very end of bulks insertion and if it is safe and faster than call `$elasticaType->getIndex()->refresh();` after every bulk sending. 
I mean something like this:

```
$offset = 0;
$limit = 500;
$sum = 1500000,

while( $offset < $sum )
{        
    $documents = [];
    $rows = $sqlDatabase->getData( $offset, $limit )

    foreach( $rows as $row )
    {
        $docData = ['name' => $row->name, 'email' => $row->email]
        $documents[] = new \Elastica\Document( $data->id, $docData );
    }

    $elasticaType->addDocuments( $documents );
    $offset += 500;
    // Source example has refresh here. After every 500 items. But I wont it at the very end of the code after all 1500000 item are in the database.
    // $elasticaType->getIndex()->refresh();
}

$elasticaType->getIndex()->refresh();  // This is what I want.
```

Is it possible to insert 1500000 documents to elasticsearch and then call `$elasticaType->getIndex()->refresh();`?

Comment: Did you tried to do this? What's wrong?

Comment: No I did not. I do it right now. I dont know what happens.

Comment: Documentation says the recommended count of items in bulk is about 500 and I dont know if it is related also to refresh call.

Comment: It says 500 is a good start. Your server power and how long you are willing to wait are your primary considerations. So basically you have to test it out and see.

Comment: I do it on localhost. So refresh after every bulk takes about 3.5 hour.

Comment: So it is possible to call refresh() at the very end.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to insert 1500000 documents to elasticsearch and then
>   call $elasticaType->getIndex()->refresh();?

Definitely yes.

A [refresh](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html) makes your document available for search, This mechanism is derived from Apache Lucene to provide near real-time (NRT) search capabilities, It uses [DirectoryReader.openIfChanged](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_3_1/core/org/apache/lucene/index/DirectoryReader.html#openIfChanged-org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader-) to reopen index.

Usually you don't have to do it yourself, a refresh is scheduled periodically
 by default, You can change the value of [refresh_interval](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#bulk) to shorter time for NRT search, or longer for performance.

Comment: Yes as I wrote 12.10.2018